# List is not printing the correct values when in nested conditional statement comparing values in a array

Tags: java, arrays, string, conditional-statements

I have  a minor problem with my code, I have this array here

```
final String[]  participatingInstitutions = {
            "Australian Catholic University",
            "Australian College of Applied Psychology",
            "Australian National University",
            "Charles Darwin University",
            "Charles Sturt University",
            "CQUniversity",
            "Griffith University",
            "International College of Management, Sydney" ,
            "La Trobe University" ,
            "Macleay College" ,
            "Macquarie University" ,
            "MIT Sydney" ,
            "National Art School" ,
            "SAE Creative Media Institute" ,
            "SIBT",
            "Southern Cross University" ,
            "Torrens University Australia" ,
            "University of Canberra" ,
            "University of New England" ,
            "University of Newcastle" ,
            "University of Sydney" ,
            "University of Technology Sydney" ,
            "University of Wollongong" ,
            "UNSW Sydney" ,
            "UNSW Canberra at ADFA" ,
            "Western Sydney University"
    };
```

This is a Array that will always remain constant and cannot be edited, this array will be used to compare values in a list

Currently my List, contains String values which Consists of University Name, followed by the courses taught at the university, so something like this

```
   AUSTRALIAN CATHOLIC UNIVERSITY
Bachelor of Accounting and Finance North Sydney (MacKillop) 103710 CSP 3F/EqP 60.65 Y
Bachelor of Arts Strathfield (Mount St Mary) 103302 CSP 3F/EqP 58.50 Y
Bachelor of Arts Blacktown 103314 CSP 3F/EqP new N
Bachelor of Arts/Bachelor of Commerce Strathfield (Mount St Mary) 103303 CSP 4F/EqP 60.35 Y
Bachelor of Arts/Bachelor of Global Studies Strathfield (Mount St Mary) 103311 CSP 4F/EqP 60.00 Y
Bachelor of Arts/Bachelor of Laws North Sydney (MacKillop) 107001 CSP 5F/EqP 71.80 Y
Bachelor of Biomedical Science North Sydney (MacKillop) 107008 CSP 3F/EqP 59.00 Y
Bachelor of Biomedical Science/Bachelor of Business Administration North Sydney (MacKillop) 107011 CSP 4F/EqP 64.30 Y
Bachelor of Biomedical Science/Bachelor of Laws North Sydney (MacKillop) 107010 CSP 5F/EqP 70.20 Y
Bachelor of Business Administration North Sydney (MacKillop) 103706 CSP 3F/EqP 58.80 Y
Bachelor of Business Administration Strathfield (Mount St Mary) 103716 CSP 3F/EqP 58.55 Y
Bachelor of Business Administration/Bachelor of Global Studies North Sydney (MacKillop) 103707 CSP 4F/EqP 58.55 Y
Bachelor of Business Administration/Bachelor of Laws North Sydney (MacKillop) 107004 CSP 5F/EqP 71.95 Y
Bachelor of Commerce North Sydney (MacKillop) 103701 CSP 3F/EqP 58.95 Y
Bachelor of Commerce Strathfield (Mount St Mary) 103711 CSP 3F/EqP 59.10 Y
Bachelor of Commerce Blacktown 103722 CSP 3F/EqP new N
Bachelor of Commerce/Bachelor of Business Administration North Sydney (MacKillop) 103709 CSP 4F/EqP 58.55 Y
Bachelor of Commerce/Bachelor of Business Administration Strathfield (Mount St Mary) 103717 CSP 4F/EqP 58.90 Y
Bachelor of Commerce/Bachelor of Global Studies North Sydney (MacKillop) 103703 CSP 4F/EqP 60.70 Y
AUSTRALIAN NATIONAL UNIVERSITY
Bachelor of Accounting Canberra 133503 CSP 3F/6P <5 Y
Bachelor of Actuarial Studies Canberra 134403 CSP 3F/6P 99.95 Y
Bachelor of Advanced Computing (Honours) Canberra 135705 CSP 4F/8P 90.50 Y
```

My code attempts to

Well this is my approach, i declare a for loop, from i = 0, to the end of my list. I declare a nested for loop from j = 0 to j = participatingInstitution array size, once I have done this. I then compare each element in my list to the participating institution, if a element is a university found in participatingInstitution array I start a for loop at i = i+1, now this is where my problem is this third for loop is responsible for printing the courses, however this is not working.

1. Look for a valid participation institution in our List, once it is found, we will print its courses.

   ```
   for(int i = 0; i<dummyLineList.size(); ++i)
   {
       System.out.println(dummyLineList.get(i));
           for(int k = 0; k<participatingInstitutions.length; ++k)
           {
              if(dummyLineList.get(i).equals(participatingInstitutions[k].toUpperCase()))
              {
                  for(int j = i+1; j<dummyLineList.size(); ++j)
                  {
                      if(dummyLineList.get(j).equals(participatingInstitutions[k].toUpperCase()))
                      {
                          System.out.println(dummyLineList.get(j));
                      }
                  }
              }
           }
   ```

**Please note in my code DummyLineList, is the List I am talking about above**

My question

**I am trying to print out the courses that each university have so for Australian catholic university, I should print the courses it has until it reaches another university(Australian national university)**

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood, but what exactly is your question?

Comment: I am trying to print out the courses that each university have so for Australian catholic university, I should print the courses it has until it reaches another university(Australian national university)

Comment: Ok, and which part is not working?

Comment: Well this is my approach, i declare a for loop, from i = 0, to the end of my list. I declare a nested for loop from j = 0 to j = participatingInstitution array size, once I have done this. I then compare each element in my list to the participating institution, if a element is a university found in participatingInstitution array I start a for loop at i = i+1, now this is where my problem is this third for loop is responsible for printing the courses, however this is not working.

Comment: It sounds like the data structure you are using (arrrays) are not doing you any favors. This kind of mapping might work better in a Map. Something like `Map<String, List<String>>`. Key is the school and the value list contains the courses.

Comment: Hmm, yea I guess that could work, So basically I would hard code all the schools into my map, and basically search for the institution(key) in my list of universities and courses, if i find a university, i just declare a counter at the second element, and iterate, all the courses and add them to my list.

As a learning experience, i just want to see how this would be implemented with a list and a array

Comment: You can check the map, if it contains the university name. If so it will return the List with all the courses for it, over which you iterate.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you are aiming to build a `Map<String,List<String>>` where key is the name of institution and list of values correspond to the courses supported by the university.

```
List<String> participatingInstitutionsList = Arrays.asList(participatingInstitutions);
Map<String,List<String>> resultMap = new HashMap<>();
String universityName = null;
for(String s:dummyListLines){
   if(participatingInstitutionsList.contains(s)){
      universityName = s;
      resultMap.put(universityName, new ArrayList<>());
   } else {
      resultMap.get(universityName).add(s);
   }
}
return resultMap;
```

I'd suggest you can try out `Set<String>` for participating institutions too. Read about `Map` and how to put and get values out of them. Hope this helps you to unfold :)

Comment: I cannot believe, i did not see this. I will mark this as the correct answer, just for learning purposes how would i implement this with a array and list data structure.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider to use Stream API which offers you to do all the job in one line.

Let your array be list1(List)

Let your school list be list2(List<List>)

```
list2
   .stream()
   .forEach(innerList-> { 
        innerList
              .stream()
              .filter(item -> list1.contains(item))
              .forEach(System.out::println);
    });
```

I wrote this for an example, maybe you may need to modify it with your requirements.